# Identify 3 terminal SMD device, probably NPN transistor or FET, marked BKZE7

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I usually manage to find myself, but with this one I am stuck completely.

[image]

[image]

I suspect it must be some kind of NPN transistor or FET. Most probably part of the marking is manufacturing site, but I also failed to find anything suitable using this pattern. Note dashes under and beyond the letters, maybe they mean something...

Maybe you can explain the marking system here and share the hints.

Comment: Can you measure the device to be able determine what type of package it is? [The SMD Codebook](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm) has some [BCX71K](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/bcx71k-d.pdf) SOT-23 devices which start with a ``BK`` marking code. A BCX71K is a PNP transistor. P.S. I edited the question to add the device marking to make it more searchable and added an ``identification`` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I can measure but can't desolder.

Comment: You don't really need to identify anything in this simple application, any small NPN or N-FET transistor will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [IRLML2803](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLML2803-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356682aff260f) N-channel MOSFET from Infineon.
[image]

Picture from [LCSC](https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20180914_Infineon-Technologies-IRLML2803TRPBF_C2590_front.jpg):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Strange as logically it must be n-channel one... I do not see information about "complementary" n-channel transistor. If that would be subject to same marking that would be the hit I guess.

Comment: IRLML2803 is actually N-channel one. https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLML2803-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356682aff260f, you referred to IRML6402 which is P-channel.

Comment: Oh sorry for that mistake